# Use LoadControl to programmatically load WebControl (not UserControl)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, webforms, custom-controls

I have a custom `WebControl` class that represents a `HyperLink` surrounded by an `li` (list item) element. I would like to be able to load this control and add it to the page programmatically.

Here is the custom web control (`ListItemHyperLink.cs`):

```
public class ListItemHyperLink : HyperLink
{
    public string ListItemCssClass { get; set; }

    public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ListItemCssClass))
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, ListItemCssClass);
        }
        writer.RenderBeginTag("li");
        base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
    }

    public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.RenderEndTag(writer);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
}
```

Here is the page I am attempting to add it to (`Test.aspx`):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Example.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <ul runat="server" ID="UnorderedList">
        </ul>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my attempt to load the control dynamically in the code-behind of the page (`Test.aspx.cs`):

```
public partial class Test : Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        var listItemHyperLink = (ListItemHyperLink) LoadControl("~/Controls/ListItemHyperLink.cs");
        listItemHyperLink.Text = "Google";
        listItemHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "http://google.com/";
        listItemHyperLink.ListItemCssClass = "li-class";
        listItemHyperLink.CssClass = "a-class";
        UnorderedList.Controls.Add(listItemHyperLink);
    }
}
```

When I try this, I get the following Exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledAssembly' to type 'System.Web.Util.IWebObjectFactory'.

This exception is thrown on the line where I call `LoadControl()`.

How can I use `LoadControl()` (or some other method) to use this control from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just instantiate your custom control and add it to the Controls collection. LoadControl is for  UserControls.

```
var listItemHyperLink = new ListItemHyperLink();
listItemHyperLink.Text = "Google";
listItemHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "http://google.com/";
listItemHyperLink.ListItemCssClass = "li-class";
listItemHyperLink.CssClass = "a-class";
UnorderedList.Controls.Add(listItemHyperLink);
```

Comment: This seems to work! I guess I was over-thinking things... I am so used to calling `LoadControl()` for UserControls that I got frustrated when it didn't work for WebControls. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ListItemHyperLink` is a server control, so you cannot load it like User control.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var listItemHyperLink = new ListItemHyperLink();
    listItemHyperLink.Text = "Google";
    listItemHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "http://google.com/";
    listItemHyperLink.ListItemCssClass = "li-class";
    listItemHyperLink.CssClass = "a-class";
    UnorderedList.Controls.Add(listItemHyperLink);
}
```

*It is kind of odd to see PageLoad using override method. It is not normal unless you have a reason behind it. It is like using Int32 instead of int. I'm just saying; I hope you don't mind.*

Comment: RE: Page_Load vs. OnLoad - I prefer overriding the base methods as opposed to using the `AutoEventWireup` convention simply because it seems cleaner. [This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2008/03/24/onload-vs-page-load-vs-load-event.aspx) touches on many of the reason why I prefer this approach. The only real downside is that you have to remember to always call the `base` version of the method within. I appreciate your concern though! :)

Comment: I read that article in few years back too. I don't normally see that override in most of Open Source projects except in old DNN. However, it is entirely up to you.